# Getkeystate return value

Tags: c

I have tried get `getkeystate(VK_SHIFT);`
to read the status of the key it works fine but the problem is sometimes it return 1 and sometimes 0 when key is not pressed and -128 or -127 when key is pressed, why it return two different values? I'm using minGW compiler in code blocks ide.

Answer (score 3):

You really need to read [the documentation for `GetKeyState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx).

In there, you'll find that the highest-order bit tells you whether the key is pressed or not.

```
SHORT state = GetKeyState( key );
bool pressed = ( state & 0x8000 ) ? true : false;
bool toggled = ( state & 0x0001 ) ? true : false;
```

Comment: Note that the comments in that documentation indicate that this isn't quite correct.  It might be that you need to test against `0x80` and `0x01`.  This would be supported by those numbers you provided in your question, and is different from a similar function `GetAsyncKeyState`